# Apache Hudi Partitioning with custom format

Tags: apache-spark, apache-hudi

I am currently doing a POC on Apache `Hudi` with spark(scala).

I am facing a problem while saving a dataframe with partitioning.

Hudi saves the dataframe with `path/valueOfPartitionCol1/valueOfPartitionCol2....`
using the property `PARTITIONPATH_FIELD_OPT_KEY`.

But my requirement is `path/COL1=value/COL2=value....` Similar to the way spark partitions the data using `partitionBy()`.

Anyone who has tried out custom partitioning with `Hudi` can help me out?

Answer (score 2):

can this help?
set config HIVE_STYLE_PARTITIONING_OPT_KEY=true as below:

```
  batchDF.write.format("org.apache.hudi")

          .option(HIVE_STYLE_PARTITIONING_OPT_KEY, true)

          .mode(SaveMode.Append)
          .save(bathPath)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom implementation of `KeyGenerator` class, Implement `override def getKey(record: GenericRecord): HoodieKey` class. In this method you get a instance of `GenericRecord` and return a class of `HoodieKey()` which allows you to define your custom logic for generating path partition